# cordova 2.0.0 gives Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'func'

Tags: javascript, android-ndk, cordova

I have created an application in cordova2.0.0,where i am calling native functions(written in c) from the java script with the help of cordova.

Previously i was doing with phonegap 1.0.0 in which the application is working properly.but when i updated it to cordova 2.0.0, i am  getting the error

```
08-07 15:24:12.527: I/Web Console(855): JSCallback Error: Request failed. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js:3698
08-07 15:22:27.815: E/Web Console(855): Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'func' at file:///android_asset/www/file.js:359
```

can any one please help me out in this problem.

code of my .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova2.0.0.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="find.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

      function js_find(fthisval){   

        ws_find(socket,js_found);           

      }
      function js_found(retval){    

       alert(retval);           

      }
      function onBodyLoad(){        

            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

      }

       function onDeviceReady()
      {

            document.getElementById('d1').style.visibility = "visible";

        }   
   </script>    
 </head>
 <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
 <div id="d1" style="visibility:hidden">
    <button id="b1" onclick="js_find("ram")">Find it plz</button><br />
     </div>
</body>
```

in find.js:

```
var Find = function() {};

Find.prototype.func = function(funcname,funcdata) { 

return cordova.exec(
  null,                 
  null,                 
  'findPlugin',     
  funcname,            
  funcdata);            
};
window.find = new Find();

function ws_find(name, param, callback){

     if(undefined == callback){

            var dataArray = [param, param, name];   

    }
    else{

        var dataArray = [callback, callback, name, param];

     }

     alert("Calling plugin function find with \r\n"+dataArray);       
     return window.find.func("find",dataArray);     

}
```

the line `return window.find.func("find",dataArray);`was suppossed to call the native java function,but it is giving me the above errors.

Answer (score 0):

Works Fine for me

Tested on Ice-Cream Sandwich and GingerBread (you may require to restructure removing the switch and having whichever option you like)

Try Debugging your version with Alerts to see till where it goes.

Also do you need to return from `cordova.exec`?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cordova</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function callPlugin(type){

    switch(type){

        case 1: 

                //Func Ptr
                window.echo = function(str, callback) {

                                cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {  callback('Nothing to echo.'); }, "Echo", "echo", [str]);

                          };    

                //Func Call           
                window.echo("echome", function(echoValue){alert(echoValue);} );
                break;

        case 2: 

                var MyClass = function (){};                //Prototype

                MyClass.prototype.echo = function(str, callback) {

                                                cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {  callback('Nothing to echo.'); }, "Echo", "echo", [str]);

                                         };


                window.echo = new MyClass();                                                    
                window.echo.echo("echome2", function(echoValue){alert(echoValue);} );   

                //OR
                //window.echo = new MyClass().echo;                                         //Add Function to Window Object
                //window.echo("echome1", function(echoValue){alert(echoValue);} );          //Call Plugin

                break;
    }   
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Plugin Test</h1>
<button onclick="callPlugin(1)">Call Plugin by Cordova 2.0.0 Method</button><br />
<button onclick="callPlugin(2)">Call Plugin by Cordova 1.0.0 Method</button><br />
</body>
</html>
```